# What is better solution than await with async in coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

I use `livedata` that collect `item` data, after it in `onClicked()` I get this data from livedata. What could be better approach for this?

```
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    lifecycleScope.async {
                        viewModel.fetchItem(args.workId)
                    }.await()
                    onClicked()
                }
```

variables in `viewModel`

```
    val item = _item.immutable()
    private val _item = MutableLiveData<ViewState<Item?>>()
[...]
```

```
// I wait here for data from first code than I collect it because item is liveData as above
    private fun onClicked() {
        val item = viewModel.item.value?.dataOrNull
[...]
```

fetchItem method

```
    fun fetchItem(id: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _item.postAsyncValue { repository.getItem(id) }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I think your code is not doing what you think it does. `fetchItem` is not a suspend function. It launches a coroutine and immediately returns without waiting for the coroutine to finish. So, your `async` coroutine that calls it doesn't wait for that result either. There's no point in using `async` at all here since the code returns almost immediately.

I'm guessing that what you're trying to accomplish is wait for `postAsyncValue` to finish setting that new value. To do this, you need to make `fetchItem` a suspend function that waits for its work to be done.

I am not familiar with this `postAsyncValue`, but my best guess is that it is a helper extension function on MutableLiveData that takes a suspend lambda, calls it, and then sets the value to the LiveData on the main thread. If this is the case, you should just do this instead so the function actually waits for the task to be done before returning:

```
suspend fun fetchItem(id: Int) = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    _item.value = repository.getItem(id) // assuming getItem is a suspend function
}

//...

lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.fetchItem(args.workId)
    onClicked()
}
```

If this isn't right, please add your source code for `postAsyncValue` and let me know.

---

Regarding your literal question, instead of using `async` followed immediately by `await`, you can use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { }`, but you would only do this if you are calling blocking code. You only need `async` when you're working with parallelism, so the compiler warns you that you're doing something silly if you immediately call `await()` after `async { }`.